# Simplified iphone In-app store implementation for built-in product features

Tags: iphone, storekit, built-in, simplification

This question is for those familiar with implementing the iphone in-app store functionality.

The app I'm building has only built-in features that are unlocked when features are purchased.  Further, any modifications or additions to store items will require an app update.  Also, it is only in English so has no localized languages for the items.

If we take those assumptions, is it feasible to skip the step of retrieving the product info with SKProductsRequest and simply use hardcoded data within the app?  While I may want to extend my app to greater complexity in the future, I'd like to know if this step to keep it simple would introduce some serious issues.

One issue might be, for instance, if we have to expect a few of the items to occasionally be unavailable due to issues on Apple's side and simply trying to purchase it and letting it fail would not be a permissible or workable option in that case (especially if it is uncommon).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that Apple would object if you used hard-coded prices in your app, although I can't say for certain that they'd reject you.

Bear in mind, however, that localization isn't just about languages.  It also gives you localized prices.  Currency values fluctuate, so we can reasonably expect the localized prices associated with a given tier to change from time to time.  The possibility of getting money from users in Canada, UK, and other territories beyond the USA seems like ample justification for using SKProductsRequest, whether it's technically and contractually required or not.

Comment: That's a good point.  I hadn't considered that price field would need to change even if I decided not to localize the text itself.  Thanks!